# How can I configure Postman so that it uses HTTP instead of HTTPS when querying an API?

Tags: windows, http, api, postman

I use Postman on Microsoft Windows 10 to test some API. By default, it uses HTTPS when querying an API. How can I configure Postman so that it uses HTTP instead of HTTPS when querying an API?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `{{protocol}}` to `http` in the address bar

[image]

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt {{protocol}} is an environment variable so if you have to edit it in many places you can also edit the environment variable itself https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/managing-environments/#editing-environment-variables   & https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/